How to create a general function type that only allows required parameters?
I'm trying to create a utility type that ensures a function has no optional parameters.  I have this working for specific function signatures, but can't figure out how to create a general type that allows any number of required parameters.
Here's what I have so far:
type NoOptionalArgs<F> = F extends (...args: infer P) => any
  ? undefined extends P[number]
    ? never
    : F
  : F;

// These work as expected:
type fn0 = NoOptionalArgs<() => any>;            // OK - no args
type fn1 = NoOptionalArgs<(x: string) => any>;   // OK - one required arg
type fn2 = NoOptionalArgs<(x?: string) => any>;  // never - optional arg

// But I can't figure out how to create a general type:
type fnType = NoOptionalArgs<(...args: any[]) => any>;  // becomes never

I want to create a fnType that:

Allows functions with any number of required parameters
Disallows functions with any optional parameters
Works with any parameter types

For example:
const good: fnType = (x: string) => 'x';  // OK
const bad: fnType = (x?: string) => 'x';  // Should error

Is this possible?

Other approaches that don't work:
type RequiredArray<T> = T extends any[] 
  ? undefined extends T[number] 
    ? never 
    : T
  : never;

type fnType = <T extends any[]>(...args: T extends RequiredArray<T> ? T : never) => any;

type fnType = <T extends readonly any[]>(
  ...args: { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], undefined> }
) => any;


There is no specific type that works this way. Furthermore, the length of a function in TypeScript is effectively unreliable because function type compatibility allows assignments that don't care about it.  Look at this playground link. The type Fn1 has a "length" of 1, presumably, but fn1.length is 0. Please [edit] to clarify your use case, with a [mre] that motivates it. Right now it's just... it seems like a false premise about function length.

@jcalz -- The use case and .length checks aren't relevant to the question.  I'm just trying to prevent allowing functions with optional args

• Okay, well there is no specific type in TS that works this way; you can't do it like const f: FnType = ⋯.  It needs to be generic. You could write a helper function to verify a value satisfies the generic type like const f= fnType(⋯), but the answer to the question as asked is "it's impossible". Are you okay with a generic solution instead, or just a "sorry, no" answer? • Even if you're not checking the length, function assignability really doesn't let you prevent optional params from coming through; see this playground link. Does that matter to you or not?

Below is a approach to creating a type, that may accepts any function with no optional parameters, and rejects any function with optional parameters. Key challenge is to detect optional parameters in a generic (type) level manner. Optional parameters in TypeScript functions become union types incldung undefined (x?: sring is x:string | unedfined).
Reasoning:

We start with a helper type that checks a tuple type of parameters
and ensures no element is optional. An optional parameter is
reflected as a type that includes undefined (like T | undefined). To
detect that one, we can use a conditional type that returns never if
the parameter is optional.

We go recrusive trough the parameters list to ensure none of them become optional. If a parameter is optional, the entire type shoud end up as never.

Once that filtered out, we can apply generic function type. The parameters which are "generic type" can adapt our checks of ensuring that the attempt to declare a optional parameter results in to a type error.


Approach / Implementation:
// This helper type checks a tuple of parameters `P` and returns a new tuple
// that is the same as `P` if no parameters are optional. If any parameter is 
// optional, it returns `never`.
type EnsureNoOptional<P extends any[]> = P extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? // Check if the current head is optional by seeing if `undefined` is assignable
    // to it. If yes, return `never`; otherwise, continue recursively.
    undefined extends Head
      ? never
      : [Head, ...EnsureNoOptional<Tail>]
  : []; // For an empty tuple, we're fine, so just return it.

// `NoOptionalArgsFunction` is a generic function type that takes two type parameters:
// - `Args` for the parameter list
// - `R` for the return type
//
// It uses `EnsureNoOptional<Args>` to ensure that if `Args` contain any optional parameters,
// the entire type collapses to `never`, causing type errors if you try to assign a function
// with optional parameters to this type.
type NoOptionalArgsFunction<Args extends unknown[] = [], R = unknown> =
  (...args: EnsureNoOptional<Args>) => R;

// Now we define a general `fnType` that can represent any function with no optional parameters.
// Since `fnType` is generic, it can adapt to any arity and parameter types, as long as none are optional.
type fnType = <Args extends unknown[], R = unknown>(...args: EnsureNoOptional<Args>) => R;

// Usage examples:

const good: fnType = (x: string, y: number) => `${x}-${y}`; // OK
// `Args` inferred as `[string, number]`.
// `EnsureNoOptional<[string, number]>` returns `[string, number]` which is valid.

const none: fnType = () => 'no args'; // OK
// `Args` inferred as `[]`, `EnsureNoOptional<[]>` returns `[]`.

const bad: fnType = (x?: string) => x || 'default'; 
// Error: `Args` inferred as `[string | undefined]`.
// `EnsureNoOptional<[string|undefined]>` returns `never` -> type error.

In summary the fnType is now a type that you can use to ensure any function is assigned to contain strictly required parameters, no optional ones. It should now handle functions with any arrangement of input paramaters.

I was trying something like that at one point, but couldn't get it to work.  Unfortunately this doesn't seem to either?  TS Playground has errors on good & none, ultimately Type '[]' is not assignable to type '[x: string, y: number]' for good

You could use an identity function that accepts only fixed argument number functions:
Playground
type IsUnion<T, C extends T = T> = (T extends T ? C extends T ? true : unknown : never) extends true ? false : true;

const checkRequire =<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(fn: IsUnion<Parameters<T>['length']> extends true ? never : T) => fn;

const good = checkRequire((x: string) => 'x');
const bad = checkRequire((x?: string) => 'x');  // Should error

